# How do I use phoenix console (iex) with heroku?

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to change some data on heroku that I normally do with iex -s , but the following command does nothing.

```
heroku run iex
```

Answer (score 6):

The command that worked was

```
heroku run iex -S mix
```

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with `phoenix` project just use:

```
heroku run iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

To launch the server in your iex console

or simply

```
heroku run iex -S mix
```

to compile the files without starting the server.

Comment: Note you may not have enough database connections available. So setting the POOL_SIZE often helps (the same as when running migrations): `heroku run POOL_SIZE=1 iex -S mix`.

Comment: oh perfect that was my issue with max db connection! Does that imply that by default it's 0 when running this command?

Comment: Using this I end up with some output (e.g. `Interactive Elixir (1.8.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)`) but never actually get into an (interactive) iex prompt.

Comment: So... It does work - at least print you welcome message. Maybe there's something wrong with input / output streams, as I assume you can't type anything, right?

Comment: @PatNowak yes. Typing is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you deploy your app to Heroku using the native release mechanism that comes with Mix since Elixir 1.8, you may simply ssh into the running dyno and remote into the running BEAM node:

```
# In your local terminal
heroku ps:exec
# In the dyno
_build/prod/rel/your_app/bin/your_app remote
```

This works out of the box.